# Using Shared Libraries with .NET Core

Tags: .net-core

I wrote my open source library, [LINQ to Twitter](https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter), with shared libraries to minimize deployment artifacts and handle platform specific features. I want to support .NET Core and am thinking that the fastest approach would be to reference the shared libraries. The Add References dialog didn't show the shared libraries, so I tried project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "LinqToTwitter.Shared": "*",
    "LinqToTwitter.Shared.net": "*"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried a few combinations of versions, but didn't get anywhere. The error messages contain something like this:

> The dependency LinqToTwitter.Shared >= * could not be resolved.

Next, I opened the *.xproj and pasted the following Imports into the Project section:

```
<Import Project="..\LinqToTwitter.Shared\LinqToTwitter.Shared.projitems"
        Label="Shared" />
<Import 
  Project="..\LinqToTwitter.Shared.net\LinqToTwitter.Shared.net.projitems" 
  Label="Shared" />
```

This doesn't show references in VS, nothing in metadata, and (as it would follow) can't reference any shared library types from a console app that references the .NET core app.

Comment: The shared libraries need to be either NuGet packages or `xproj` projects in order to reference them in your `project.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news - Visual Studio 2017 now allows .NET Core library projects to reference Shared projects.

Answer (score 0):

if library is in the same solution you can reference it using `target:project` something like

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "LinqToTwitter.Shared": {"target": "project"},
    "LinqToTwitter.Shared.net": {"target": "project"}
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and received an error message: The dependency LinqToTwitter.Shared could not be resolved. Same for LinqToTwitter.Shared.net.

Comment: are these 2 libraries developed using .net core?

Comment: if might wanna look at this article `Running .NET Core apps on multiple frameworks` https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/28/running-net-core-apps-on-multiple-frameworks-and-what-the-target-framework-monikers-tfms-are-about/

Comment: Those are shared libraries. I'm unaware of whether I can create .NET Core shared libraries. Thanks for the article link.

Comment: if I'm not mistaking you cannot reference classic .Net libraries in .Net Core

Comment: Looks like I should move off of Shared and towards Standard - looking at this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/