# How to import a public ref class from linux shared library using dotnet core

Tags: c#, c++, shared-libraries

I have looked at some of the other post on this and either they are too simple, too old. I would prefer not to use visual studio as I am not very familiar with it and I do not have it installed. I am using the dotnet core cli in ubuntu. I have a shared library `vendor.so` I am trying to use a method that is in a public ref class inside `vendor.so` This is the code

`vendor.h`

```
namespace Vendor_namespace{
    public ref class Vendor
    {
    public:
        int myMethod(...)
```

`MyCSharp.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Program {
       class Program {
        [DllImport("Vendor.so")]
        static extern class Vendor;
public static void main(string[] args) {
  Vendor foo = new Vendor();
  foo.myMethod(...)
}
```

This is the error I am getting when running the code

```
Program.cs(76,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Vendor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/../../MyCSharp/MyCSharp.csproj]
Program.cs(76,36): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Vendor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/../../MyCSharp/MyCSharp.csproj]
```

Comment: And what is the problem with above code?

Comment: I tried adding a reference by using dotnet add reference vendor.so and I got this message `Project `Vendor.so` is invalid.`

Comment: I also tried editing the project.json and doing a restore, but It still hasn't been able to pick up that the so is there

Comment: I tried using the solution from here, but it didn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134489/using-shared-libraries-with-net-core